# Probability theory: Is there a generalized version of this property?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I know from undergraduate Probability that given a r.v. $X:\Omega \to R$ then 
$$ Z:\Omega \to R \text{ is } \sigma(X) \text{-measurable } \Leftrightarrow  \exists f:R\to R \text{ Borel-measurable such that } Z=f(X) $$

But what about the case where $X$ is given with values in a general topological space $(S,\mathcal{B}(S))$ ? is there any $f$ ( $\mathcal{B}(S)$-measurable) ?

In case not, is there any intermediate result, any condition on $S$ somewhat more general than being $R$ for such result to hold?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the property would hold if $S$ is hausdorff, i.e., you can separate any two distinct points with disjoint open sets. $Z$ is a function of $X$ means $X(\omega_1)=X(\omega_2)$ implies $Z(\omega_1)=Z(\omega_2)$. If $Z(\omega_1)\neq Z(\omega_2)$, find disjoint open sets $A\ni Z(\omega_1),B\ni Z\omega_2)$. Then $Z^{-1}(A)\in\sigma(X), Z^{-1}(B)\in\sigma(X)$, and $Z^{-1}(A)\cap Z^{-1}(B)=\emptyset$. If $X(\omega_1)=X(\omega_2)$ then the preimage of any open set in the range space of $X$ contains neither or both of $\omega_1,\omega_2$. Since such preimages generate $\sigma(X)$, you can probably use something like the monotone class theorem to show the property (a set contains neither or both of $\omega_1,\omega_2$) extends to $\sigma(X)$, a contradiction to $A,B\in\sigma(X)$. I don't know if the hausdorff property is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In full generality, given measurable spaces $(X,\mathcal M)$ and $(Y,\mathcal N)$, a function $f:X\to Y$ is said to be $(\mathcal M,\mathcal N)$-measurable if $f^{-1}(E)\in\mathcal M$ for all $E\in\mathcal N$. So for any topological space $(\mathbb X,\mathcal T)$, we have the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(\mathcal T)$, and given a set $\Omega$ and a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ on $\Omega$, we can consider $(\mathcal F, \mathcal T)$-measurable functions. No restriction on $\mathcal T$ is necessary, and in fact, there are $\sigma$-algebras which are not generated by toplogies at all: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87838/is-every-sigma-algebra-the-borel-algebra-of-a-topology